# Logical way of saving thousands of combinations of multiple polygons in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, maps

Just looking for a way to save data in mysql of thousands of combinations.

Suppose I have two big polygons and 1st one has 100 child polygons and 2nd one has 150.
Now each 100 of 1st polygon has a connection and weight to each of 150 polygons of the second one. Moreover each has a forward and backward weight and one self to self weight
So I have (100*150)+(100+150) = 15,250 possible outcomes and have to save all in my mysql db.

How can I have a simpler way of making this db without creating 15,250 rows?

I am working on connecting multiple area of a city to multiple areas of a different city and a value for each of those connection (forward, backward and self to self). So if any other service is available for this work, please feel free to address those.

Comment: there are specialized hierarchical databases which are designed to do such things. You can split your data and save it in different systems(entities in relational db and relations in hierarchical db) or save everything in hierarchical db.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will look into hierarchical dbs.